# Using an array as key in map C ++

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary

Basically, I need to find all matching anagrams to a word. What I was doing was using an array of size 26 to represent the letters in a word.
Ex:

```
abcdefg={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
aaaaaaa={7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

This is how I'm creating the array.

```
//stringtemp is a C++ string representing the word.
//letters is a size 26 int array representing all the letters in the string.
for(int i=0;i<stringtemp.length();i++)
{
    letters[stringtemp[i]-65]+=1;
}
```

And this is how I'm storing the array in the map.

```
dictionary[letters].push_back(stringtemp);
```

So, am I doing something wrong or is this impossible in C++. In all the other answers I found, they suggested to use a vector as the key, but that won't work in my case(I think.)

Comment: As the answers below reflect, a C style array will not copy as you're expecting it to.

Comment: Including the definitions of `dictionary` and `letters` would help.

Answer (score 11):

All of `std::array<T, 26>`, `std::string` and `std::vector<T>` are perfectly valid key types for a `std::map`, since they all define less-than comparison operators. Note that `std::array<T, 26>` is similar to `std::tuple<T, T, ..., T>`, and comparison is defined lexicographically, very similar to string comparison.

```
#include <array>
#include <map>

typedef std::array<unsigned int, 26> alphabet;

std::map<alphabet, std::string> dictionary;

dictionary[{{1, 0, ..., 8}}] = "hello";
```

With a bit more work, you can also make all of those types keys for an `std::unordered_map`, though you'll have to add a bit of boilerplate code from Boost (using `hash_combine`).

Comment: `std::string` isn't really in contention of being a key type.

Comment: @LucDanton: `string` will do in a crunch, and it's the only type which has a ready-made hash function defined for it. So if a hash table turns out to be computationally indispensable, then it'd be easier to use a string than define your own hash operations on a vector. Otherwise you have a valid point of course.

Comment: When I try that, I get an "expected initializer before '<' token" error. Also, when I try to import array, it returns an array file not found error. Any idea what the cause is?

Comment: @user1525047: You'll need C++11 support for `std::array`. In GCC, add `-std=c++0x` to your compiler command. Alternatively, use `<tr1/include>` and `std::tr1::array`.

Answer (score 2):

[std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) allows you to provide a Compare operator in the constructor.  You may need to provide such a Comparator in order for two arrays {1,....} and {1,....} to match since they may be different actual objects.

Answer (score 1):

The key type in a map must have an `operator<` defined for it. You could define `operator<` for your array type, but there's a much simpler approach: sort the letters in each word into alphabetical order, and use that sorted string as the key.

Comment: A string consisting of 12000 `'a'`s would be fairly inefficient that way, though.